# print IP Address and Username(operating System or Software) in oracle report

Tags: oracle11g, oraclereports

is there any possibility that print the IP address and Operating System or Software schema on the report of that client where from the report is printed

Comment: Using only oracle?  Probably not.

Comment: how to print ip address and username in oracle report

Answer (score 0):

Google for `sys_context`.

```
SELECT SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER') ,  SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'IP_ADDRESS') ,  SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER')  FROM DUAL;
```

Result of this select will relevant if user is connected directly to oracle not by web application

Comment: it is not working in oracle report i want to use this information at the end of the report page but still error ora-00600

Comment: Did you check google for ora-600? This is the generic internal error number for Oracle program exceptions. It indicates that a process has encountered a low-level, unexpected condition.

Comment: so what i can do to print this information in report